# Facebook login fails, "something went wrong"

Tags: android, facebook

I'm making an app with Facebook login. I got the login to work stand alone, but now when integrating it with my other activity, it won't login. It comes with the error message "Sorry, something went wrong. We're working on it and we'll get it fixed as soon as we can", and then I press back and it correctly says that login has been cancelled, so I know it makes it that far. Can anyone see whats wrong? I'm working on the same project from my home computer and laptop. Does this somehow mess up something with the facebook-id from my strings.xml?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.nan.spymap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    private TextView info;
    private LoginButton loginButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
        loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MapActivity.this, MapActivity.class));

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                info.setText("Login attempt cancelled.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                info.setText("Login attempt failed.");
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

My AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.nan.spymap" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

My activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nan.spymap"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.1'
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29333335/any-example-showing-how-to-login-using-facebook-sdk-4-0-in-android-either-by-usi

Comment: I'm not sure what to look for there, Naveen :/

Comment: I noticed that this problem was happening only when I used a new fb profile that I made for testing...but when I used my own fb profile...then it worked fine.

Comment: Please someone help, facing the same issues too. Although the login did work this morning again just once, then went back to the error message.

Answer (score 6):

Your issue might be because of the permissions you are sending in
loginButton.setPermissions("email", "public_profile", "user_friends")
Make sure to use a Facebook valid keys

Answer (score 1):

Issue is arising for everyone who is trying to integrate facebook sdk in android app. Facebook is doing some updations at their end. But working fine for signed apks.

Answer (score 1):

It was my keyhash, FB would not allow it to be run from 2 different machines as developer. Change the keyhash on fb console and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Currently in a battle with the same exact problem.

The fault appears to be in already existing permissions. If the user has already given permission to the Facebook App, "Something goes wrong" on Facebook's end when a login is initiated. Revoking permissions will make it work once and then it breaks again.

**Not sure yet how to permanently fix this yet.**
Will update this answer if I manage to find anything.

**EDIT 1:**

Found an ugly, temporary workaround. Still digging. It breaks Single Sign On.

```
loginButton = ( LoginButton ) findViewById( R.id.login_button );
loginButton.setLoginBehavior( LoginBehavior.WEB_ONLY );
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @KrzysztofWolny It might not be the best possible answer, but it does provide a temporary workaround for the problem while Facebook is fixing their side. I couldn't find any other ways of making it work on non-signed apks. Thank you for the pointers on SO though, will take notice!

Comment: See my answer for my problem, found out on my own. Hope it helps u

Comment: There are multiple posts related to this on SO, none describing the correct solution. Does anyone have proper working solution ?