# Facebook Android SDK finishing current activity

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to login using the Facebook Login Manager, it is finishing the current activity and returning the activity result to the previous activity. I checked the context which I am using for login process. It is the instance of the current activity. I am not sure why this is happening.

This is the code which I have written for fb login.

```
val loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance()
val callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()
loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, this)
loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(currentActivity, arrayListOf("public_profile", "email", "user_friends"))
```

Comment: did you getting data on activity result ?

Comment: Not in the current activity but in the previous activity. By previous I mean, the activity which launched the current activity.

Comment: yes that means you logged in successfully and get result. check response what you getting in where you called this.

Comment: I called this in current activity. But I got the response in the previous activity. There is no problem is logging in, I am able to login successfully. But the current activity is getting finished.

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30320269/5110595) hope it will help you.

Comment: Tried exactly same thing. It is still finishing the current activity.

Comment: did you call finish() anywhere in your current activity? check it once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162890/discussion-between-puneet-kala-and-hemant-parmar).